# Выбор хостинга для чего-то сложного. VPS vs Cloud.

Tags: облако, vps

Мне потребуется несколько серверов выполняющих разные функции (memcached, application, workers, databases). Всё это добро нужно будет связывать друг с другом и передавать много данных, т.е. нужно чтобы сервера находились в одном датацентре.

Думаю использовать Amazon. Всё правильно? Есть ли какие-либо преимущества у пачки VPS/VDS? Что посоветуете, друзья-админы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Облако имеет то преимущество, что пиковые запросы легко масштабируются, плюс может быть упрощение установки и обслуживания за счет того, что часть функций берет на себя провайдер облака. Если же это не так, то пачки VPS/VDS вполне подходят (серьезные проекты делались и до массового пришествия облаков).

Answer (score 4):

В идеале надо брать дедик или пачку дедиков.Аргументы:

1. У VPS как и у облаков есть один большой недостаток - дисковая система. Она общая для всех пользователей ноды, соответственно при всей её сказочной производительности, она будет узким горлышком любой производительной VPS или облака.
2. Избыточная нагрузка со стороны ОС. Например вы взяли 4 VPS на облаке с оплатой за использованные ресурсы. ОС на сервере занимает 2-3Гб и 256 Мб в памяти + нагружает диск операциями чтения-записи, кушает процессорный ресурс и т. п. в итоге вы разделили нагрузку но повысили расходы.
3. Коммуникация, тоесть сообщение между всеми этими машинами, даже в рамках одного ДЦ - будет куда больше тормозить вас, чем любая другая характеристика железа. Вынос memcached на отдельный сервер это эпический бред. Memcached хорош тем, что хранит записи в RAM, Memcached на другом серваке это хуже чем если бы хнаить данные на локальном диске.
4. У облака есть лимит равный железу установленому в кластере. Если в кластере стоит 8-ми ядерный проц, вы будете ограничены мощностью этого проца. Если 64Гб Ram - это ваш предел.
5. Стоимость аренды VPS мощностью равной восьмиядерному процу с 8 Гб оперативки намного превышает стоимость дедика. Аналогичная стоимость по предельной нагрузке подобного железа в облаке будет стоить вам 4-5 дедиков. VPS и облака хороши только для стартапов и сайтов на 5-10К посетителей, дальше - просто экономически не целесообразно.

Вот мои рекомендации по мере роста нагрузки: - Для начала брать мощный дедик с RAID 10. - Взять дедик под ДЬ, монтировать в одну стойку с вашим дедиком. Сервер ДБ соединить через отдельный ethernet 1Gb порт с рабочим дедиком. - При дальнейшем росте нагрузки взять сервер для распределения нагрузки (на котором будет крутится только nginx и proxy_pass на другие сервера и, возможно, будет лежать статика на винтах) и добавлять по серверу для обработки веб или ДБ, а также для статики по мере нагрузки. - Купить маршрутизатор для объединения своих серверов. - Забить одну стойку, другую, третью, построить датацентр...

Почему купить? Оборудование взятое в аренду конечно кажется дешевле, но если проект серьёзный и денежный, то выгоднее купить своё оборудование и брать в аренду только колокейшн и канал. Окупается за 6-12 мес.

Answer (score 1):

Серьёзные проекты по умолчанию не могут быть сделаны на VPS хостинге, потому как если у тебя будет что-то глючить на реальном серваке, то легко протестить железо и начать углубленно вникать в настройки сервака, зная уже на 100% что проблема только там. А обзор можешь глянуть [здесь](http://www.hosting-obzor.ru/dedicated-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Бери [VPS rootwelt](http://infoblog1.ru/forsite/server-v-evrope). Самое лучшее решение на данный момент.